# Selecting path component based on logic

Tags: angular

Is it possible for me to hit a path and select what component gets loaded based on a bit of logic. The example I'm trying to sort through at a basic level is if someone hit `/`, I'd usually do something like:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: LandingComponent,
}
```

However, if someone is logged into the site, I'd like them to go to `HomeComponent` when they hit `/`:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
}
```

I'd like to pick which of those two components loads based on other values. I know I can redirect them if I wanted logged in users to go to `/home`, using a Resolver, but other than creating a wrapper component with a dynamic component within it, not sure if this can be done the way I'm imaging. I've also seen that I can change the router config, but the SO question I saw was early 2016, so I'm not even sure if it's valid anymore.

Comment: Look into route guards; you can only allow them to go to home if they are logged in, and redirect to a landing page on a separate route otherwise.

Comment: As I mentioned, I know I can redirect them, for example with a Resolver, but I was curious about having a different component chosen at the same path. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
{
  path: 'foo',
  component: GLOBAL_CONDITION ? FooComponent : BarComponent
}
```

But as others have said ... for this specific scenario a  route guard is often better. It can the prevent access to child routes as well so the user could not get around your security by typing in a direct url to one of your other routes.

Comment: Yah, as I said, I know I can use a Guard, but I don't know how I can get a guard to change the component. Best I know is a guard will let me redirect (I will definitely have security guards up), so are you suggesting that the best solution is to have separate paths; not different components based on condition?

Comment: A guard can redirect to another component, but yes it would need a separate path.